# Math Logic Not Working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a simple program that checks if two numbers added together is == to the textbox answer(mathAnswer), but when I enter in the correct answer and click the submit button I keep getting "Incorrect" from answerstatus label? Does anyone know why?

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

namespace FinalProjectPhoneVersion
{
    public partial class MathPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MathPage()
        {
                    Random random = new Random();


                    int randomNumber1 = random.Next(0, 10);
                    int randomNumber2 = random.Next(0, 5);
         int answer = randomNumber1 + randomNumber2;

            int counter = 0;
            int strikeCounter=0;
            InitializeComponent();
            String welcomeString = (String)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["enterNameBox"];

            RadioButton hardRadio = (RadioButton)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["radio_button2"];
            RadioButton easyRadio = (RadioButton)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["radio_button1"];

            welcomeLabel.Text = "Welcome " + welcomeString;
        //    difficultyLevelLabel.Text = "Difficulty Level: " + easyMode;
            scoreLabel.Text = "Score: " + counter;
            strikerCounterLabel.Text = "Answers Wrong: " + strikeCounter;
            if ((bool)easyRadio.IsChecked == true)
            {
                randomNumber1 = random.Next(0, 10);
                randomNumber2 = random.Next(0, 5);



            }
            else if ((bool)hardRadio.IsChecked == true) {
                randomNumber1 = random.Next(0, 6);
                randomNumber2 = random.Next(0, 100);
            }
            if (answer.ToString() == mathAnswer.Text) {
                answerStatusLabel.Text = "Correct!";
            }
            else if (answer.ToString() != mathAnswer.Text)
            {
                answerStatusLabel.Text = "Incorrect!";
            }
            scoreLabel.Text = "Score: " + counter.ToString();

          //  if (difficultyList.SelectedIndex == 0)
          //  {


             //   mathQuestion.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber2) + " + " + Convert.ToString(randomNumber2);//add this line 
                num1Label.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber1);//add this line 
                num2Label.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber2); //and this line
                mathSign.Text = "+";

          //  }
          //  else if (difficultyList.SelectedIndex == 1)
          //  {
               // answer = randomNumber1 * randomNumber2;
             //   num1Label.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber2);//add this line 
               // num2Label.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber1); //and this line
         //   }

        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void submitAnswer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison has to happen after your user clicks the submit button. Therefore, the comparison code should be placed in the button click event handler for that button, like so:

```
private void submitAnswer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (answer.ToString() == mathAnswer.Text) 
        {
            answerStatusLabel.Text = "Correct!";
        }
      else 
        {
            answerStatusLabel.Text = "Incorrect!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I can't use static with answer so it doesn't exist in the current context? Unless theres a way to globally define answer like static int answer in a windows phone app?

Comment: You could declare `randomNumber1` and `randomNumber2` as global static variables i.e. declare them as `static int...` outside the constructor, assign them the random value in the constructor and then use them in the event handler.